# Debugging application crash on Linux (app not tainted)

Tags: linux, debugging, crash, arm

This application crashes unexpectedly (it is running on ARM x64 processor). I don't see any error log messages before the crash. Just the following text appears on the terminal (2 different crashes are shown below):

[image: Crash #1 text]

[image: Crash #2 text]

I know I can debug that issue by finding the line at which the PC register (or LR) is pointing to. But the issue is that I don't know what is the base address is. `PC is at 0x7fb828dc50` is a virtual address if I understand correctly.

If I can get the physical address instead, I can use addr2line command to find out which line caused that issue.

Can anyone help me with that?